# Excel VBA Run Time Error 91

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner to macros. I got a

> run time error 91

in line

```
Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
```

Any suggestions on how to debug it?

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. Please give sample of when did error came and for what data and for what macro, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you do not have current workbook in protected view so try testing first

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
End If

End Su
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the `ActiveProtectedViewWindow` returns `Nothing`, thus you cannot `Edit` it. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activeprotectedviewwindow-property-excel):

> Returns a ProtectedViewWindow object that represents the active Protected View window (the window on top). Read-only. Returns Nothing if there are no Protected View windows open. Read-only

Check whether it is `Not Nothing` by using the following:

```
Sub TestMe()
    If Not Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing Then
        Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit "pwd"
    End If
End Sub
```